# Gradle - Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules kotlin-compiler-1.9.22

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, duplicates

The problem appears after added an implementation in dependencies of custom sdk project containing kotlin compiler.
I already upgraded the libraries to the latest versions both side (app and sdk)

> Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
> found in modules kotlin-compiler-1.9.22
> (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler:1.9.22) and listenablefuture-1.0
> (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0) Duplicate class
> org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls found in modules annotations-23.0
> (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0) and kotlin-compiler-1.9.22
> (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler:1.9.22) Duplicate class
> org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls$Capitalization found in modules
> annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0) and
> kotlin-compiler-1.9.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler:1.9.22)

```
dependencies {
    implementation "conflicting_custom_sdk_that_contains_kotlin_compiler_etc:0.0.1"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to solve this instead of using `implementation` to your sdk.You can use `compileOnly` it should look like this.

```
compileOnly "conflicting_custom_sdk_that_contains_kotlin_compiler_etc:0.0.1"
```

Comment: That didn't help.
The conflicting dependency is:
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler:1.9.22'
defined in custom sdk. Even adding it to a pure android app generates Duplicate Classes error.